# SQL Group by Query help needed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with survey results. It basically contains the question ID, the response(s) chosen, and the user ID of the person taking the survey. Some sample data is -

```
Q_ID   /   Response ID   /  Response  /  Username
23     /       14        /    Male    /  testuser1
23     /       14        /    Male    /  testuser2
23     /       15        /   Female   /  testuser3
24     /       16        /    Male    /  testuser2
24     /       17        /   Married  /  testuser3
25     /       19        /  Engineer  /  testuser1
25     /       21        /   Surgeon  /  testuser3
```

I also have another simple table with the Question ID, and the actual corresponding question. For example, Question with Q_ID 23 is "What is your Gender?"

What query can I use in order to get the results similar to this -

```
Question No  /       Question       /  Response # / Response / Count
23           /  What is your Gender /     14      / Male     / 27
23           /  What is your Gender /     15      / Female   / 14
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't quite do what I'm looking for.. (I am a beginner)

```
 Select a.Q_ID, b.Question, a.response_id, a.response, count(a.response)
 from survey_responses a, survey_questions b 
 where a.Q_ID = b.Q_ID group by count(response)
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you've explained what's wrong here. What is the query displaying when you run it?

Comment: @hichris123 . . . It's producing an error, because aggregation functions are not allowed in the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select a.Q_ID, b.Question, a.response_id, a.response, count(a.response)
from survey_responses a, survey_questions b 
where a.Q_ID = b.Q_ID 
group by  a.Q_ID, b.Question, a.response_id, a.response
```

Group by the columns you want to count up, not by the count.

Edit in :  Newer syntax using joins...you should probably be creating your sql like this (since 1992)

```
SELECT a.Q_ID, b.Question, a.response_id, a.response, count(a.response)
FROM survey_responses a
INNER JOIN survey_questions b ON b.Q_ID = a,Q_ID
group by  a.Q_ID, b.Question, a.response_id, a.response
order by a.Q_ID
```

1 more edit...put in the order by

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT a.Q_ID, b.Question, a.response_id, a.response, count(a.response)
FROM survey_responses a
INNER JOIN survey_questions b ON b.Q_ID = a,Q_ID
GROUP BY a.Q_ID
ORDER BY count(a.response)
```

Comment: You have switched it to newer syntax (joins vs the where clause holding the join), but the way he has it written works.  Answer does not solve his grouping issue

Comment: @Twelfth I'm not quite sure what the problem is anymore. I can't tell if the query isn't executing, or if it's not displaying something correctly.

Comment: Is there any way to also sort this by question_id?

Comment: Mysql probably wouldn't return an error anyway ;)   Don't group by count, group by the columns he has in the select clause

Comment: @SainathKrishnan From what I can tell, you were using the `GROUP BY` to order stuff, so I added an `ORDER BY` and changed the `GROUP BY` to group the id's, not the count's.

Comment: @hichris123 I wouldn't expect this to execute at all since there is an aggregate function in the select and none of the columns appear in the group by

Comment: @Dan - MySQL will run these and return funky results with incorrect grouping...somehow MySQL likes providing incorrect results instead of an error.

Answer (score 1):

slight changes needed. I believe this should work:

```
Select a.Q_ID, b.Question, a.response, count(a.response)
from survey_responses a, survey_questions b 
where a.Q_ID = b.Q_ID
group by a.Q_id, response
```